# IOS Crash reports SDK

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I am an IOS Developer, some of my customers say that they cant open my APP and it crashes as soon as i open.

i want to find out why this happen, is there a SDK that can alert me if any of my IOS APPS crash.

Comment: No, I think there is no such type of SDK available. you need to find problem in your code with setting breakpoint(Debugging). and see when your app will be crashed and try to find the solution , if you can't get solution then post code here and then someone can help you. because there are several reason for app crash..

Comment: @BadalShah You are incorrect. There are several such tools. But such questions are off-topic on SO.

Comment: THere are many options!!! BEst is to use hockey app!!!

Comment: @rmaddy: extremely sorry. i don't know regarding this. can you give me few name of such tools if possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement Crashlytics in your app.It will tell you the exact line in the code for crash.

This is the [link](https://try.crashlytics.com) and it free to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can get crash reports directly from iTunesConnect.  From the Apple docs:

> Where can I find the crash reports for my apps? To find crash logs for
>   an app that is or was available on the App Store:
>
> Go to My Apps and select your app Select the platform version you
>   would like to view Go to the Additional Information section at the
>   bottom of the page and click Crash Reports If your app has not
>   received any reports of crashes the link for Crash Reports will not be
>   visible in iTunes Connect.
>
> Crash reports are also available within Xcode if you upload an app
>   with the symbols. For more information, review the Crashes Organizer
>   Help documentation.